# Abstract Base class not returning correctly

Tags: c++, abstract-base-class

I am still not quite fully understanding Abstract Base Classes. This is what I have created for my assignment and it seems to mostly work except that it won't return anything that was added through the derived classes. Whenever I choose hasDMA or lacksDMA I don't get the result returned from color or style.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "DMA.h"

using namespace std;

const int RECORDS = 1;
const int LEN = 40;

int main()
{
    ABC * p_records[RECORDS];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < RECORDS; i++)
    {
        char temp[LEN];
        int temprate;
        char choice;

        cout << "\nEnter label name: ";
        cin.getline(temp, LEN);
        cout << "Enter Rating: ";
        cin >> temprate;

        cout << "Enter 1 for lacksDMA or 2 for hasDMA: ";
        while (cin >> choice && (choice != '1' && choice != '2'))
            cout << "Enter 1, 2: ";
        if (choice == '1')
        {
            char tempcolor[LEN];
            cout << "Enter the color: ";
            cin.getline(tempcolor, LEN);
            p_records[i] = new lacksDMA(temp, temprate, tempcolor);         
        }
        else
        {
            char tempstyle[LEN];
            cout << "Enter the style: ";
            cin.getline(tempstyle, LEN);
            p_records[i] = new hasDMA(tempstyle, temp, temprate);           
        }
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
            continue;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < RECORDS; i++)
    {
        p_records[i]->View();
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < RECORDS; i++)
    {
        delete p_records[i];
    }

    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
    cin.sync();
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

DMA.cpp

```
#include "DMA.h"

using namespace std;


ABC::ABC(const char * l, int r)
{
    label = new char [strlen(l) + 1];
    strcpy(label, l);
    rating = r;
}

ABC::ABC(const ABC & rs)
{
    label = new char[strlen(rs.label) + 1];
    strcpy(label, rs.label);
    rating = rs.rating;
}

ABC::~ABC()
{   
}

ABC & ABC::operator=(const ABC & rs)
{
    if (this == &rs)
        return *this;
    delete [] label;
    label = new char[strlen(rs.label) + 1];
    strcpy(label, rs.label);
    rating = rs.rating;
    return *this;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const ABC & rs)
{
    rs.View();
    return os;
}

void ABC::View() const
{
    cout << "\nLabel: " << label << endl;
    cout << "Rating: " << rating << endl;
}

baseDMA::baseDMA(const char * l, int r) : ABC(l,r)
{
}

lacksDMA::lacksDMA(const char * l, int r, const char * c) : ABC(l,r)
{
    strncpy(color, c, 39);
    color[39] = '\0';
}

lacksDMA::lacksDMA(const ABC &rs, const char * c) : ABC(rs)
{
    strncpy(color, c, 39);
    color[39] = '\0';
}

void lacksDMA::View() const
{
    ABC::View();
    cout << "Color: " << color << endl; 
}

hasDMA::hasDMA(const char * s, const char * l, int r) : ABC(l,r)
{
    style = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
    strcpy(style, s);   
}

hasDMA::hasDMA(const char * s, const ABC & rs) : ABC(rs)
{
    style = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
    strcpy(style, s);
}

hasDMA::hasDMA(const hasDMA & hs) : ABC(hs)
{
    style = new char [strlen(hs.style) + 1];
    strcpy(style, hs.style);
}

hasDMA::~hasDMA()
{
    delete [] style;
}

void hasDMA::View() const
{
    ABC::View();
    cout << "Style: " << style << endl;
}
```

DMA.h

```
#ifndef DMA_H_
#define DMA_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Abstract Base Class
class ABC
{
private:
    char * label;
    int rating;
public:
    ABC(const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
    ABC(const ABC & rs);
    virtual ~ABC() = 0;
    virtual ABC & operator=(const ABC & rs);
    virtual void View() const;
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const ABC & rs);
};

// Former Base Class Using DMA
class baseDMA: public ABC
{
private:

public:
    baseDMA(const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
};

// derived class without DMA
// no destructor needed
// uses implicit copy constructor
// uses implicit assignment operator
class lacksDMA : public ABC
{
private:
    char color[40];
public:
    lacksDMA(const char * l = "null", int r = 0, const char * c = "blank");     
    lacksDMA(const ABC & rs, const char * c);
    virtual void View() const;
};

// derived class with DMA
class hasDMA : public ABC
{
private:
    char * style;
public:
    hasDMA(const char * s = "none", const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
    hasDMA(const char * s, const ABC & rs);
    hasDMA(const hasDMA & hs);
    ~hasDMA();
    hasDMA & operator = (const hasDMA & rs);
    void View() const;
};

#endif
```

Comment: This is way too much of code. Please post the section where you seem the problem is.

Comment: How about `std::string` and `std::vector`??? Your code is full of dynamic allocation... God help those who will have to debug it.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code (except that you should `delete[] label` in `ABC::~ABC()`, or better yet make it `std::string`). Make sure that your code is identical to the code posted here. Also, describe example input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Make sure that in your code `ABC::View` is really declared as `virtual`, and that keyword `const` is either in all 3 function signatures, or in none of them. That is most important part.

Comment: When I run it and I put in Test for label, 10 for rating and select 1 for lacks DMA it then asks for color which it should and I enter red. Everything seems to be going good at that point. When the record is displayed however the label and rating are correct but nothing displays for color. It only displays Color:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you said that the string "Color:" is displayed, but the examaple input "red" is not displayed. Because "Color:" is displayed this is not an issue of something failing in the abstract/virtual part of the code (otherwise even "Color:" would not be displayed).

The fail is in the input. When you read the choice of '1' or '2' you read only that one character, but the user actually entered extra new line as well, and so next `cin.getline` will consume this extra new line and return an empty string. You should stick with the `cin.getline` for all the input, even if the input is just one character, and even if the input is a number. It is easier to never use `cin >>`, and handle the errors in input by yourself than to mix `operator>>` with `getline` and then handle all border cases when they don't play nice together.

Altough this is not part of the answer, here are some general advices:

1) In C++ avoid `new char[x]` whenever possible. Use `std::string` for strings and `std::vector<char>` for very rare cases when `std::string` is not good enough.

1b) You forgot to `delete [] label` in destructor of `ABC`. If it was a `std::string` you wouldn't have to worry about these things.

2) It is okay to `use namespace std` in source files (.cpp), and only after all the `#includes`, but never use it in header files (.h). Never! Use full names in header files (like `std::string` instead of `string`)

EDIT: So, some code example is required. Like I said, stick with `cin.getline`, and avoid `operator>>`, even if the input is just one character, and even if the input is an integer:

Replace line `cin >> temprate;` with this:

```
    cin.getline(temp, LEN);
    temprate = strtol(temp, NULL, 10);
```

Replace two lines of `while` loop

```
    while (cin >> choice && (choice != '1' && choice != '2'))
        cout << "Enter 1, 2: ";
```

with these lines of `for` with exit in the middle (my preferred way of endless looping):

```
    for (;;)
    {
        cin.getline(temp, LEN);
        choice = temp[0];

        if (choice == '1' || choice == '2')
            break;

        cout << "Enter 1, 2: ";
    }
```

Comment: So basically when I am asking for input for the hasDMA or lacksDMA it is carrying over a blank line into the next question?

Comment: Yes, new-line in input is not consumed by `cin >> choice` part of the code.

Comment: Even if I change the input for choice to an integer it's still not working. I can't seem to figure out how to get this input without carrying over a blank spot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I do better with examples and this, although direct, helped a lot. I now see what you mean by using getline instead of cin >>. seeing as temp was used as a holding place for other items though I did have to change the input for the label to tempname and have temp just copy it over using strncpy. Thanks again

Comment: @user2849274 you're welcome. If this is a correct answer then you should mark it as such, by clicking on white check mark to the left.